# TikZ standalone fails to generate PDF with tight layout when using loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, loops, standalone, crop, bounding-box

Something quite strange happens when I try to add loops in my code (they are actually not really loops, but edges from one node to itself, controlled by `in` and `out` arguments.

The following is the code I am working on (look for `---> [Comment]` for the line(s) that give the problem:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{color,xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes,
                positioning,
                decorations.pathmorphing} 
  
%% My "standalone" scheme by TikZ
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
%% Nodes
\draw (0,0) node (origin) {};
\node[at=(origin.center),circle, minimum size=2cm,draw=black] (x) {X};
% %% Loops ---> THIS MAKES THE BOUNDING BOX NOT TIGHT
\path (x) edge[->,out=250,in=150,min distance=0.25cm,looseness=5] node[very near end, below right]{\bf\Huge{-}}(x);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How to avoid this issue and automatically get the PDF without white borders and without possibly, cropping it outside or in postprocessing?

I am running this code by Overleaf, so there is supposedly no software bug; rather, it should be just me doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Please make your code compilable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `bbox` tikz library providing `bezier bounding box` like this

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bezier bounding box]
\node[circle, draw, ultra thick] (activity) {X};
\draw (activity) to[out=110, in=220, min distance=0.25cm, looseness=5] (activity);
\draw[red, dashed] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\node at (0,1) {Bezier bounding box};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw, ultra thick] (activity) {X};
\draw (activity) to[out=110, in=220, min distance=0.25cm, looseness=5] (activity);
\draw[red, dashed] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\node at (0,2) {Normal bounding box};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: A node with a loop and tight red rectangle]
[image: A node with a loop and loosely fit red rectangle]

Comment: Thanks. I ignored the existence of the `bbox` library, and your suggestion works. My original code compiled fine by Overleaf, but I edited it accordingly to generate a MIME example.

Comment: In the [PGF manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) on CTAN there is no mention of the `bbox` library. Where is it listed? Where can I read about it from 'official' sources? Here is a link to [`tikz-bbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-bbox?lang=en) on CTAN.

Comment: I do not understand your question. In your link, there is a link to the manual. You can read about it in the manual.

Comment: keyword search in the PGF manual that I linked, show no results for `bbox`. I provided the link. A quick related question: how do I set globally the `bezier bounding box` option? When I specify in the preamble: `\tickzset{every picture/.style={bezier bounding box}}` it does not appear to work.

Comment: Direct link to the manual: http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-bbox/pgfmanual4bbox.pdf

Comment: When you compile stuff, there should be no warnings and absolutely no errors. If there are, you need to read them and correct your code. Try `\tikzset{every picture/.style={bezier bounding box}}`